# PHP possible to initial array with value from same array?

Tags: php, arrays, path, initialization, self-reference

I want to save current path information in an Array and one field is a part of another. Can I access a field of the same array during initialization?

```
$this->path = array
(
     'rel_image' => '/images',
     'document_path' => '/a/file/path',
     'path' => $this->path['document_path'].$this->path['rel_images']
);
```

or do I have to initial them one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array still is undefined while you're defining it. However you can define other (temporary) variables to do so on the fly:

```
$this->path = array
(
     'rel_image' => $r = '/images',
     'document_path' => $p = '/a/file/path',
     'path' => $p.$r
);
```

However that normally should not be needed, as you're duplicating data within the array. Just saying, you can do whatever you want :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize them one by one.

It is best to think of `array` as a constructor. The array itself doesn't completely exist until after the function call is complete, and you can't access something which doesn't completely exist in most circumstances.

Comment: Function call? Of the constructor?

Comment: Well, `array` is a function which returns an array. But it is like a constructor in that it returns an initialized object. But it is... `array` is special.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you have to initialize one by one, beacuse $this->path is being filled after array() function is done.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the assignment you're trying to do isn't a functional one.

Code:

```
 <?php $array = array('foo' => 'bar', 'bar' => $array['foo']); ?>
 <pre><?php print_r($array); ?></pre>
```

...renders the following:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
    [bar] => 
)
```

As the array is created at one time, not once per element, it will not be able to reference the values in the same statement as the assignment.